# Scaling characters to surroundings

Tags: animation

I've been wanting to animate a monster short and I've used BlenderGIS is get my city, but when I import the monster the scale blender is giving the model doesn't match the scale of the reference building. Monster being 108 meters tall and the building being 207, but the monster visually is only a fraction of the buildings size. Is this a bug or am I just too concerned with the numbers.

Comment: Hello. You mean the dimension of the building is 207 meters, the monster 108 meters but it appears to be much smaller than that? Could you show a screenshot with the objects and the property panel showing the dimensions?

Comment: Are those numbers really the _Dimensions_ of the objects or the _Scale_?

Comment: to help you the fastest way and really find the error it would be the best if you could provide the .blend file